# Error response "proxyconnect tcp: EOF" from daemon when running docker run hello-world in docker quickstart terminal

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-toolbox, docker-quickstart-terminal

I'm running docker toolbox on windows version 10.0.15063 behind corporate proxy, and I'm getting the following error when i run the command `docker run hello-world`

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: EOF.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'
```

I'm getting the same error on attempting to login to docker using `docker login`.
I've already tried exporting HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY in /Docker Toolbox/start.sh and adding the same to my environment variables but none of these approaches seem to be working.

Here's my `docker info`

```
$ docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 18.09.6
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84
runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.14.116-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 18.09.6 (TCL 8.2.1)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 989.4MiB
Name: default
ID: PNCR:EWZF:D4O3:7KDP:UW7W:4NEO:YGTT:CHWV:VF5U:YTE6:GD66:WKHS
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
HTTP Proxy: http://xxxx:xxxx
HTTPS Proxy: https://xxxxx:xxxx
No Proxy: 192.168.99.100
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Here's what i get on ssh-ing into the default machine and running `sudo vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile`

```
CACERT=/var/lib/boot2docker/ca.pem
DOCKER_HOST='-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376'                                                                             
DOCKER_STORAGE=aufs                                                                                                                                     
DOCKER_TLS=auto                                                                                                                                      
SERVERKEY=/var/lib/boot2docker/server-key.pem                                                                                                               
SERVERCERT=/var/lib/boot2docker/server.pem                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
export "HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy2:8080"                                                                                                                      
export "HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy2:8080"                                                                                                                    
export "NO_PROXY=192.168.99.100"
```

I'm I missing something? I've been working on this for the last hour without any luck.

Comment: I would try uninstalling and reinstalling Docker Toolbox

Comment: @Alon I actually figured out what the issue was. Refer to the answer provided below

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. 
I was initially using corporate network while working on this, and the networking team has blacklisted every ip and then white-listed the trusted ones. That was what was causing the whole problem while trying to connect to an external registry.

These are the steps I followed to fix the issue:

1. I switched to my personal network then disabled the proxy ie. Under *Internet Properties* > *Switch to automatic Configuration* > *Automatically detect settings.*
2. Removed the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY exports from start.sh in C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox
3. Opened Windows *Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules > Add New Rule*; Then
   Created a Custom rule with a range ip range of 1-100, then named it Docker.
4. Deleted the *.Virtualbox* folder from *C:\Users\myusername**
5. Restarted Docker Quickstart Terminal. It created a new default docker-machine and updated the configuration settings, and now pulling images from external registries is working fine.

Comment: "I switched to my personal network then disabled the proxy"
What if this is not an option?